# Django cannot find an app with manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django, macos, django-manage.py, django-taggit

i am running Mac OS X 10.7 and I succesfully created a project in django by using
    django-admin.py startproject MyBlog. In this folder i have manage.py, another folder titled MyBlog and an app folder which i created called MainBlog.

I needed to add this module, and a taggit module to my settings.py folder so i did (probably incorrectly).

Here it is..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
'MainBlog.taggit',
'MainBlog',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I have also tried

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
'MainBlog.taggit',
'MyBlog.MainBlog',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Neither of these work. They all return this error...

```
Error: No module named MainBlog
```

Any help would be greatly appreiciated. Ive been struggling with this for hours!

Comment: Does MainBlog.taggit throw an error as well? Usually I just add `appName` to INSTALLED_APPS and it works. Did you try just `'MyBlog'`

Comment: How did you create your app? Did you run `python manage.py startapp MainBlog`, or did you simply create the `MainBlog` folder?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving is because django doesn't recognize your app, `MainBlog`, as a python package.

Django modules are simply Python packages. You need an `__init__.py` file inside your app directory (`MainBlog`) to get django to recognize it. See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

There are two ways to fix this.

### 1) Initialize your app with the django script (recommended)

```
python manage.py startapp MainBlog MainBlog
```

The `startapp` command is [documented on the django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination).
This creates a few files in your `MainBlog` folder to start you out:

```
MainBlog/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

### 2) Manually add an `__init__.py` file to your MainBlog directory

```
touch MainBlog/__init__.py
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much this worked. Altough now it is raising the error, no module named taggit. Do i need to put another init.py file in the django-taggit folder on maybe the MyBlog one? THanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are following the django-tagg itinstallation instructions: http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

    `pip install django-taggit`

Then add `'taggit'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Hmm. for some reason it is still not finding it. I installed it correctly and i have it as 'taggit' in my Installed apps yet it still yiedls no results. My folder is like this..                             MyBlog,MainBlog,build,djanggo-taggit is this correct? It is where pip installed it by default